# splashscreen loading trouble

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for 0->100
                SplashScreen.SetCurrentTitle("Loading " + Math.Ceiling(procent).ToString() + "%");
                //SplashScreen.Instance.Invalidate(); doesn't helps :(
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(20);
```

that's splashscreen but I can see only 1->18 and then just wait 18->100 but can't see :(

how to show other 18->100 :)

this ?

```
        public static BeginDisplay() : void
    {
        Instance.Visible = true;
        unless (Instance.Created)
        {
            Instance.CreateControl();
        }

        _=SetWindowPos(Instance.Handle, (HWND_TOPMOST :> IntPtr), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
        alphaBlend = if(Instance.FadeIn) (15 :> byte) else (255 :> byte);
        Instance.SetBitmap((Instance.BackgroundImage :> Bitmap), alphaBlend);
        when (Instance.FadeIn)
        {
            mutable tmrFade : Timer = Timer();
            tmrFade.Interval = 10;
            tmrFade.Tick += EventHandler(_fadeTick);
            tmrFade.Start();
        }
        Instance.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that your initialization code performs one long operation thus blocking  the message queue. You should do the folllowing:

1. Instruct the main thread to allow splash screen updates (via `DoEvents`). This should be done periodically while performing initialization.
2. Display the splash screen in an alternate thread and update its status from a dedicated percentage variable set from the primary thread (the one that performs initialization).

Comment: @Femaref, you're definitely right. But from what I saw in the source code of the question, it is too early for the guy to dive into multi-threading. @nCdy, no offense

Comment: But I'm making doEvents... don't know if I can make it in new thread :P btw that's awesome code >_< but doEvents doesn't helps here . . . where I must to add it ... ?

Comment: @nCdy, yes you are. But your initialization code is the one that is blocking the splash screen. Could you provide it also so that a clearer suggestion could be thought of?